# How to make .php extension to load as .html

Tags: apache, cpanel

I'm using CPANEL, there is option Apache handlers.

How can I make the .php extensions load like .html?

For example,

```
example.com/index.php
```

should be

```
example.com/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

convert .php extension to .html extension in subdirectory using .htaccess file (convert .php extension to .html extension for all files in particular folder using .htaccess file)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subdirectory name

Example

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /gallery

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.).php
RewriteRule ^(.).php $1.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.).html
RewriteRule ^(.).html $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Tried, but it says Error 404. :(

Comment: exactly copied the mentioned code ?

remove gallery, because you don't have a gallery folder. change this: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Comment: Yes. The exact code without the subdirectory or /htdocs. Error 404.